# change source code and update jupyter notebook but retain variables

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm using a Jupyter notebook (Python2 kernel) to display the results of simulations that depend on a local library `mylib` that I've written. In the notebook, I have

```
[1]  ## import library
     import mylib
```

---

```
[2]  ## run simulations
     X = mylib.simulateX()
     Y = mylib.simulateY()
     Z = mylib.simulateZ()
```

---

```
[3]  ## plot data
     mylib.disp_data([X,Y,Z])
```

I often find myself making changes to one of the methods, say `simulateY`, but wanting to retain the results of existing simulations `X` and `Z` (or even just changing `disp_data`). That is, I'd like to reimport my library after changing the source code of `simulateY` to generate `newY` but still have access to `X` and `Z`. Is there a way to do this without writing `X` and `Z` to a file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I unload (reload) a Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module)

Comment: @jjjjjj did my answer work for you?

Comment: @JamesDraper: thanks for checking. Yes, it worked great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think that this might `autoreload` magic might work for you;

```py
import my_lib
# Use these commands in the same cell.
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```